# Async Await Promise.all Array.map not behaving as expected. Not Sure Why

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have the below in an async function in one of my projects.  `matchCamera`, `matchIP`, and `matchAudio` all return either boolean, or an error.

If an error gets returned I would expect for it to fall into my master catch so I can handle it, but this isn't happening.

```
try {
    // .... Additional code here

    const typecheck = await Promise.all(
        evoCfg.cameras.map(async camera => {
            if (camera.type === 'H264') {
                return await matchCamera(camera);
            } else if (camera.type === 'RTSP') {
                return await matchIP(camera);
            } else if (camera.type === 'AUDIO') {
                return await matchAudio(camera);
            } else {
                // Motion JPEG
                return true;
            }
        })
    );

    //  .... additional code here

    console.log('results:);
    console.dir(typecheck, {depth: null, colors: true});
} catch (e) {
    console.error('In Master Catch:', e);
}
```

My output that I keep getting when I cause an error condition is:

```
results:
[ true,
true,
true,
true,
true,
true,
Error: MAC for IP Cam not found on Network: 00:11:22:33:44:55
  at matchIP (/file.js:58:15)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7),
true ]
```

I am expecting:

```
In Master Catch: MAC for IP Cam not found on Network: 00:11:22:33:44:55
  at matchIP (/file.js:58:15)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

---

```
const matchIP = async source => {
    let arpScan = [];

    for (const c in obj.arr){
        if(obj.arr[c].name === source.source) {
            try {
                arpScan = await scannerP();

                let arpIdx = searchObjArray(source.mac, source.mac, 'mac', 'mac', arpScan);
                if(arpIdx === -1) {
                    // not found on network
                    throw new Error(`MAC for IP Cam not found on Network: ${source.mac}`);
                }

                for (const cs in obj.arr[c].sources) {
                    if (
                        obj.arr[c].sources[cs].id === arpScan[arpIdx].mac &&
                        obj.arr[c].sources[cs].url === `rtsp://${arpScan[arpIdx].ip}/${source.streamPort}`
                        ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                let recorderIdx = searchObjArray(
                    'rtsp',
                    source.mac,
                    'fmt',
                    'id',
                    obj.arr[c].sources
                );

                source.streamAddress = arpScan[arpIdx].ip;
                obj.arr[c].sources[recorderIdx].url = `rtsp://${arpScan[arpIdx].ip}/${source.streamPort}`;
                return false;
            } catch (e) {
                return e;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you handling errors in those three functions? If you're catching the error and not re-throwing it or returning a rejected promise... you're essentially converting it to a resolved promise.

Comment: _"all return either boolean, or an error."_ - do your `match*` functions _return_ an Error or _throw_ an Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `matchIP` function has in it

```
try {
  // ... code
catch (e) {
  return e;
}
```

So it is returning the error as a value rather than throwing it for your outer block to catch.

Also, as other people have pointed out. You are mostly defeating the value of `Promise.all` by using `await` in your `map` function. Take the `await`s out.

Comment: so instead of `return e;` do a `throw e;`?

Comment: @shaun do not use `try...catch` at all unless you are going to do something useful with the exception. Just remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> The [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

You are defeating the purpose of `Promise.all`. It expects a list of promises, but you're giving a list of values from a promise.

```
const typecheckArray = await Promise.all(
  evoCfg.cameras.map(camera => {
    if (camera.type === 'H264') {
      return matchCamera(camera);
    } else if (camera.type === 'RTSP') {
      return matchIP(camera);
    } else if (camera.type === 'AUDIO') {
      return matchAudio(camera);
    } else {
      // Motion JPEG
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
  })
);
```

Also, `Promise.all` returns an array of values.